# To disable the option "to open a new tab" of context menu of browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is posible disable the option "to open new tab" in context menu of browser, when i do click right about a href link?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: you can only prevent the context menu, not it's options

Comment: … and even preventing right click will only works if the browser allows it (good browsers let the user configure that.) And in 99.999% of cases it is a bad idea anyway – the user is used to their browser’s UI behaving in a certain way, and messing with that is seldom a good choice.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information, i take note, to disable to context menú i use: document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};